# Counting comments on given content type via custom manager

Tags: python, django

I am attempted to annotate a count of comments to the querysets of a model.

I can do this as a one of like this, and it works:

entry_type is a content type object.

```
popular_posts = Post.objects.all().annotate(\
        comment_count=Sum("id")).extra(select={
            'comment_count': """SELECT COUNT(*) FROM django_comments
                WHERE django_comments.object_pk = Blogger_post.id
                AND django_comments.content_type_id = %s"""
        }, select_params=(entry_type.id,)).order_by('-comment_count')
```

However when I try

```
popular_posts = Post.custom_manager.all()

#custom_manager
class PostManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
    return super(PostManager,self).get_query_set().all().annotate(\
            comment_count=Sum("id")).extra(select={
                'comment_count': """SELECT COUNT(*) FROM django_comments
                    WHERE django_comments.object_pk = Blogger_post.id
                    AND django_comments.content_type_id = %s"""
            }, select_params=(entry_type.id,)).order_by('-comment_count')
```

there is a comment_count but it's not the expected value.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:
I still don't know what the problem with this is, but this works

```
class PostManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
    return super(PostManager,self).get_query_set().all().extra(select={
                'comment_count': """SELECT COUNT(*) FROM django_comments
                    WHERE django_comments.object_pk = Blogger_post.id
                    AND django_comments.content_type_id = %s"""
            }, select_params=(entry_type.id,)).order_by('-comment_count')
```

Comment: Any reason why you use `entry_type.id` in the first but `str(entry_type.id)` in the second?

Comment: just a remnant from testing.  I've tried it both ways